# What changes should I make to make this captioning method work for multiple slideshows?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, slideshow

Currently I'm using innerHTML to set the caption of each slide in a slideshow using the image's alt text. This works for a single slideshow, but not multiple, as I would rather not copy and paste the code and create a new variable and function for each new slideshow. The other parts are generalisable, because they use classes instead of IDs, but this isn't. What method would be recommended instead?

**HTML**

```
                <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1,slideshow2)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1,slideshow2)">&#10095;</a>

                <!-- Image text -->
                <div class="caption-container">
                    <p id="caption"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
      <!-- Thumbnail images -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="img_wooods.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="The Woods" onclick="currentSlide(1, slideshow2)">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Cinque Terre" onclick="currentSlide(2, slideshow2)">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Mountains and fjords" onclick="currentSlide(3, slideshow2)">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Grassy Landscape" onclick="currentSlide(4, slideshow2)">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Nature and sunrise" onclick="currentSlide(5, slideshow2)">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Snowy Mountains" onclick="currentSlide(6, slideshow2)">
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showSlides(n, slideshow) {
  var i;
  var slides = slideshow.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = slideshow.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideshow.currentSlideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideshow.currentSlideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideshow.currentSlideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideshow.currentSlideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideshow.currentSlideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

Comment: What is keeping you from using `caption` as a class and searching the slideshow for it? Just remember to get the first element of that array, since it returns an array, even if there is only one item.

Comment: Iterate over the slideshow wrapper elements and add event handlers using `addEventListener`. Since you are iterating over the wrappers, you can simply use `wrapper.querySelector` and `wrapper.querySelectorAll ` to target only each slideshow's own elements.

Comment: @Ant This results in the first slideshow caption being set to the image alt text, rather than the caption of the slideshow the user is clicking on. I am attempting to come up with a way to set the caption of the relevant slideshow, similar to the way I'm changing slides.

Comment: That makes little sense, if you are passing the slideshow in the function and you call `slideshow.getElementsByClassName("caption")` it should return only the caption of that slideshow.

Comment: @Ant I'm not sure what the issue is then, all I can see is that it does not want to work

Comment: Try to console.log the Element list to see what you get

Comment: @Ant It is apparently undefined. I used slideshow.getElementsByClassName("caption")[0], was that correct?

Comment: It should be... Provided your slideshow does include the caption as well as you did change the `id` to `class`